# How can wxPython's dc.DrawText() set the color? Workaround - dc.DrawTextList, using foregrounds

Tags: wxpython

I couldn't find a way to set the color so that dc.DrawText would give any text color but black.
My latest attempt is in the code fragment (workaround commented out):

```
        title_text = "Parabola"
        title_font = wx.Font(wx.FontInfo(20))
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        pen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour("blue"), thickness, wx.SOLID)
        dc.SetPen(pen)
        dc.SetFont(title_font)
        title_w, title_h = dc.GetTextExtent(title_text)
        title_pt = wx.Point(int(x_mid - title_w / 2), int(y_min-title_h))
        dc.DrawText(text=title_text, pt=title_pt)
        ###dc.DrawTextList(textList=[title_text], coords=[title_pt], foregrounds=[wx.Colour("blue")])
```

My simple workaround is to use dc.DrawTextList.  The following working code fragment (DrawText call commented our):

```
        title_text = "Parabola"
        title_font = wx.Font(wx.FontInfo(20))
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        pen = wx.Pen(wx.Colour("blue"), thickness, wx.SOLID)
        dc.SetPen(pen)
        dc.SetFont(title_font)
        title_w, title_h = dc.GetTextExtent(title_text)
        title_pt = wx.Point(int(x_mid - title_w / 2), int(y_min-title_h))
        ###dc.DrawText(text=title_text, pt=title_pt)
        dc.DrawTextList(textList=[title_text], coords=[title_pt], foregrounds=[wx.Colour("blue")])
```

It was simple enough that I stopped looking for anything more elegant.  However, it would be nice to have a more direct method to draw a single text string in a specified color.  The fragment is long because I wanted to include my actual working code.

Answer (score 0):

Got to look at the documentation more closely.
The short answer is to use dc.SetTextForeground().
Code fragment:

```
            dc.SetTextForeground(wx.Colour("blue"))
            dc.DrawText(text=tline, pt=title_pt)
```

Comment: It seems you found the answer precisely 48 seconds, before me! :)

Comment: Yes, I find it embarrassing when a closer look at the documentation points out the answer I should have seen earlier.

Answer (score 0):

> DrawText (self, text, x, y)

> Draws a text string at the specified point, using the current text font, and the current text foreground and background colours.

Thus dc.SetTextForeground(wx.RED) for example